# Cannot render values in django template using for loop

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

So i have a zipped list inside my view and I have passed it into context like this:

```
 combined_data = zip(hostnames_list, values, values1, values2, values3, values4, values5)

    context = {'combined_data': combined_data}

    

    return render(request, 'base/snmp-table.html', context)
```

but when i try to render this data into the django template like this, the data is not displayed:

```
<table>
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Hostname</th>
          <th>Value1</th>
          <th>Value2</th>
          <th>Value3</th>
          <th>Value4</th>
          <th>Value5</th>
          <th>Value6</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {% for host, val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6 in combined_data %}
      <tr>
          <td>{{host}}</td>
          <td>{{val1}}</td>
          <td>{{val2}}</td>
          <td>{{val3}}</td>
          <td>{{val4}}</td>
          <td>{{val5}}</td>
          <td>{{val6}}</td>
      </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>

  
  </table>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function () { 
      location.reload();
    }, 2 * 1000);
  </script>
```

The lists which are zipped are not empty because when i do this inside my view:

```
for host, val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6 in combined_data:
        print(host, val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6)
```

I get the output in my console

```
10.1.1.1 not found not found not found not found not found not found
10.1.1.2 not found not found not found not found not found not found
```

Note: 'not found' is the value inside list. Any insight please? thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the `zip` function returns an iterator, which can only be iterated over once. To fix this, you can convert the zipped object to a list by using the `list()` function, like so:

```
combined_data = list(zip(hostnames_list, values, values1, values2, values3, values4, values5))
```

This way, you can iterate over the `combined_data` variable multiple times in your template.